# How to change view and fires the logic located in view model for one click?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0

To clarify my question I would like to describe what my application has:

*Views:*

- ApplicationView
- MainView
- EditEmployeeView

and their *View Models*:

- VMApplication
- VMMain
- VMEditEmployee

I have learned how to change view by Command of Button in MVVM pattern

VMApplication code to change view from EditEmployeeView to MainView:

```
private ICommand saveEditingEmployeeCommand;
public ICommand SaveEditingEmployeeCommand
{
    get
    {
      if (saveEditingEmployeeCommand == null)
      {
         saveEditingEmployee = new RelayCommand(
            p => SaveEditingView());
      }

         return saveEditingViewCommand; ;
      }
    }
public void SaveEditingView()
{
   CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels[0];
}
```

It works perfectly - the view changes to the MainView from EditEmployeeView, however the code just changes the view and not fires the logic of saving employee(SaveEmplMethod()) located at VMEditEmployee:

```
private ICommand saveEmplCommand;
public ICommand SaveEmplCommand
{
   get
   {
      if (saveEmplCommand == null)
      {
        saveEmplCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    p => SaveEmplMethod());
      }
        return saveEmplCommand;
    }
}
private void SaveEmplMethod()
{
  using (EmplEntities db=new EmplEntities())
  {
    var currentEmpl = db.Employees.First(q=>q.Empl==selectedEmpl);                
    currentEmpl.Name="Bob";
    db.SaveChanges();                
   }
 }
```

My question is **how to save edited Employee and change view to Main View?** Is my approach right?
Any examples and advices would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `CurrentPageViewModel` can have associated `...Changed` event which you can use in other view models to run some custom logic. This event can tell about old view model and new view model, so you can run some logic before another view become current and before it become non current.

Comment: @Sinatr oh, thanks! Is this approach used in production code? Maybe have a link to show an example?

Comment: @Sinatr could you shower write some code, please:)